# Loops and microcontrollers

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, microcontroller

This is what I am trying to figure out, I have a MC9S08AW60. It has two timers and I am trying to configure or just check for a tick from the timer, ie , I just want to check when the overflow flag changes. the basic design of the code is:

```
PTFDD = 0xFF;
int j,ch_nbr;
// LED mask values:
#define mLED0    0x01
#define mLED1    0x02
#define mLED2    0x04
#define mLED3    0x08
#define mLED4    0x10
#define mLED5    0x20
#define mLED6    0x40
#define mLED7    0x80



void main()
{

  While(j>0){

  ch_nbr++;
  if (ch_nbr == 8)  ch_nbr = 0;
  if (ch_nbr == 0)  PTFD = mLED0;  // Turn LED0 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 1)  PTFD = mLED1;  // Turn LED1 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 2)  PTFD = mLED2;  // Turn LED2 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 3)  PTFD = mLED3;  // Turn LED3 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 4)  PTFD = mLED4;  // Turn LED4 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 5)  PTFD = mLED5;  // Turn LED5 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 6)  PTFD = mLED6;  // Turn LED6 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 7)  PTFD = mLED7;  // Turn LED7 on, other LEDs off
  Mydelay();
   }
   } 
 void Mydelay(int *j)
{

 if (TPM1SC_TOF == 0) j=0;
 else j=1;
 return j;
 }
```

The idea is to check if the value "j" AND concurrently decide if the LED's should light up or not!
This code doesnt work.Its been sometime since I used the C programming. I am a little shaky and need some help. A proper explanation would be nice.
Please consider the following link for the Datasheet of the MCU:
http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9S08AW60.pdf

Can the Following function be replaced instead of the existing Mydelay:

```
int Mydelay(int& j)
{
 if(TPM1SC_TOF == 0) j=0;
 else j=1;
 return j;
}
void main()
{
  PTFDD = 0xFF;
int j,ch_nbr;
// LED mask values:
#define mLED0    0x01
#define mLED1    0x02
#define mLED2    0x04
#define mLED3    0x08
#define mLED4    0x10
#define mLED5    0x20
#define mLED6    0x40
#define mLED7    0x80   
  While(j==1)
 {
  ch_nbr++;
  if (ch_nbr == 8)  ch_nbr = 0;
  if (ch_nbr == 0)  PTFD = mLED0;  // Turn LED0 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 1)  PTFD = mLED1;  // Turn LED1 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 2)  PTFD = mLED2;  // Turn LED2 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 3)  PTFD = mLED3;  // Turn LED3 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 4)  PTFD = mLED4;  // Turn LED4 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 5)  PTFD = mLED5;  // Turn LED5 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 6)  PTFD = mLED6;  // Turn LED6 on, other LEDs off
  if (ch_nbr == 7)  PTFD = mLED7;  // Turn LED7 on, other LEDs off
 }
 Mydelay();
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is you've got 3 opening brackets and 5 closing brackets.

Comment: Is this compiled? You call MyDelay without parameter. MyDelay function doesn't do any delay. Where j is defined? How LED_poll is called? You need to work with this question...

Comment: What is the overflow flag for?

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: the overflow flag is basically a Modulo counter ie a register which just counts upto 0xFF and then starts counting again from 0x00.At every switch the FLAG goes off!!

Comment: @AlexFarber: it doesnt compile. it just marks the function with all the errors.

Comment: Actually, I can't figure out what you are asking. Also, how is MyDelay() supposed to delay anything?  Update your question with an explanation of what TPM1_TOF is for starters. And what does your current code do? Why doesn't it work? Does the LED light up always, or never? What are the symptoms? Generally, excellent questions here on Stackoverflow, receives excellent answers.

Comment: Is TPM1_TOF a hardware counter which "overflows" to 0?  If so, you need to busy wait with a while() loop on that, to make a delay around that. Also, if that is the case, how fast does it count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might want to use [bit shifting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/69809) to simplify your code significantly (because that's what you are essentially doing, shifting a bit).

This means you don't need to have 8 constants for each position, but simply use the `<<` operator to move the bit one position to the left on each iteration:

```
int MoveToLeft(int bitPosition)
{
    // shift left
    bitPosition = bitPosition << 1;

    // reset to '1' when we shift through all 8 bits
    if ((bitPosition & 0xFF) == 0)
        bitPosition = 1;

    return bitPosition;
}
```

Next, better way than polling the timer value is to use [interrupt routines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). You need to setup a function which will be invoked automatically whenever your timer finishes counting.

I am not sure if your code even works like this. Is your timer's purpose to create a delay between LED changes? Does your timer automatically resets itself? Something like this would be more logical if the timer only serves to wait before transition:

```
while (1) // repeat indefinitely
{
     // shift the bit
     ch_nbr = MoveLeft(ch_nbr);
     PTFD = ch_nbr;

     // while the timer is counting, do nothing
     while (TPM1_TOF == 0) 
     { }

     // reset the timer
     (not sure about this part, check your docs)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your perfectly stated reply. As for bit shifting i will keep that in mind. Yes, according to the datasheet, the timer resets itself. SO all i need to check for is when the flag goes ON/OFF when there is a switch between   0xFF to 0x00. if you take a look at the datasheet page 170, the TOF section.

Answer (score 1):

Well if this is a cut-paste of your code you've got a few things to fix:

- 1st this line: `While(j>0){` I don't see j declared or defined anywhere. The compiler should've generated an error on that, and `While` should be lowercase `while ( j > 0 )`.
- Same with `ch_nbr`.
- When you call `MyDelay()` you wrote it to take an `&int` and you probably meant `(int *j)`, then you didn't pass it anything.
- `If` needs to be lowercase `if`
- And yes, as the comments showed you have 3 opening brackets `{` and 5 closing ones `}`.

Fix those, make sure it compiles now and then tackle any logic.

Comment: i have made the required changes!

Comment: Great! Is it working as expected now? Or are more changes needed?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have more closing brackets than opening brackets. Try correcting this by matching brackets (indentation will help).
2. You didn't declare the variables `j` and `cn_nbr`  anywhere, but you use them.
3. C statements are lowercase (`while`, not `While`).
4. You are calling `Mydelay()` without parameters, when `Mydelay(int &j)` expect a parameter. Also, `&j` returns the address of the variable `j`. I think you want `int *j` here. Read more about pointers.
5. Use `switch` or `if ... else if` instead of `if ... if ... if ...`. Your code work both ways, but using switch or if else is faster.

Consider learning more about C programming here: http://www.cprogramming.com/